# Setting values in a datatable from RowUpdating

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

```
 protected void gd_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox txtAuthor;
            TextBox txtBook;
            dt = new DataTable();
            dt=(DataTable)ViewState["dt"];
            GridViewRow gdr = gd.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            if (gdr != null)
            {
                txtAuthor = (TextBox)gd.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtAuthor1");
                txtBook = (TextBox)gd.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtBook1");
                dt = (DataTable)ViewState["dt"];
                string txtAuthorName;
                string txtBookName;


            if (txtAuthor != null && txtBook!=null)
            {
                txtAuthorName = txtAuthor.Text;
                txtBookName = txtBook.Text;

                int i=0;
                dt = (DataTable)Session["dt"];
                for (; i < gd.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (e.RowIndex == i)
                    {
                        dt.Rows[i][0] = txtAuthor.Text;
                        dt.Rows[i][1] = txtBook.Text;
                        ViewState["dt"] = dt;
                        gd.DataSource = dt;
                        gd.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        dt = (DataTable)ViewState["dt"];
        gd.DataSource = dt;
        gd.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please write something about your problem as well

Answer (score 1):

The error is probably because of trying to access a row of data table that does not exists. To assign values to `datatable` rows you have to check if you have that row in `datatable` you are checking the rows of `grid` instead of `datatable` You do not need loop here as you can directly access `datatable` rows with index, simply check if `e.RowIndex` is valid row index of `datatable`.

```
if (e.RowIndex <= dt.Rows.Count)
{
    dt.Rows[e.RowIndex][0] = txtAuthor.Text;
    dt.Rows[e.RowIndex][1] = txtBook.Text;
    ViewState["dt"] = dt;
    gd.DataSource = dt;
    gd.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: @user2255135, if the answer addressed your question, you might consider accepting it by clicking on the green checkmark under the vote arrows (see more info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)). Tks.